# How to create attribute for async methods only

Tags: c#, asynchronous, attributes, compile-time

I need create attribute for only async methods. If this attribute is applied to a synchronous method then must generate compile-time error.

How can I create such attribute?

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What for do you need this?

Comment: There is no such built-in feature, but you can easily create it yourself; define the new attribute and create a Roslyn analyser to check it is only applied to async methods.

Comment: You could use PostSharp to create an attribute with these kind of restrictions: http://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-validation